# Creating a list based on a list definition template

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, templates

I have a list definition in my solution, and i want programmatically be able to create a list based on that list definition, could anyone tell me how to do that?

```
<ListTemplate
    Name="Mylise"
    Type="10778"
    BaseType="0"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="410"
    DisplayName="My new List"
    Description="My own list"
    Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>
```

Comment: What kind of list?  In what kind of application and at what point?  What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to generate classes, you can use tt files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try
{
  SPList list = null;
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite/"))
  {
     using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
     {
      //List Will be Created Based on this ListDefinition
- OOB Custom List Definition
      //00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100

        foreach (SPList _list in web.Lists)
        {
          if (_list.Title.Equals("TestList"))
          {
              list = _list;
          }
        }

        if (list == null)
        {
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         Guid listID = web.Lists.Add("TestList", //List Title
                      "This is Test List",      //List Description
                      "Lists/TestList",         //List Url
                      "00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100", //Feature Id of List definition Provisioning Feature – CustomList Feature Id
                       10778,                     //List Template Type
                     "101");      //Document Template Type .. 101 is for None

           web.Update();
           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

         }
        }


     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Hope This is Helpful For you :)

Comment: Nice answer, just a small detail - the last parameter for Document Template Type is wrong.  100 is "None", 101 is "Word Document".  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448694(v=office.14).aspx or here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448694(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 12):

Call

```
var customTemplate = yourSPWeb.ListTemplates["Mylise"];
```

to get the list template object, then

```
yourSPWeb.Lists.Add("List title", "List description", customTemplate);
```

to create the list.